# How do I stop md-card from taking full horizontal width? How do I place them side by side?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-material

I've been using angular2-material in my side project and have been unable to stack cards horizontally. They automatically take up the full width. Limiting the width through a css class does not cause them to stack. All subsequently placed cards will still be placed below the previous.

I would appreciate some guidance on getting the cards to sit side-by-side horizontally (and appropriately wrapping when they get to the edge of the screen).

Comment: can you please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flex-box`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ntmrtnwu/

*HTML*

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Replace the child divs with the `<md-card></md-card>` selector but do place them inside a parent div with the `flex` properties. Should work. If you can't make it work I can create a plnkr with material2

**EDIT**

Material 2 plunker with functioning flex

http://plnkr.co/edit/zHndJLKRSvTQUV1G6Bgp

Comment: Thanks! I was working on replying to @haxxxton's feedback by making a plunkr, but you've answered before I finished making it irrelevant. I wasn't sure if I needed to wrap them in a flex-box or if there was something built in to angular2/material. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Ijwu No problem :)

Comment: i think we could also use `display: inline-block` which all browsers support it

Answer (score 2):

**Flex-box** is a latest approach as shown in other answer but you might face problem with few browsers as it is not fully supported by all browsers.So, Other than that, **`Twitter-bootstrap-css`** can also be used as followed,

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
             <md-card>
                  ...
             </md-card>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-6">
              <md-card>
                   ...
              </md-card>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: True that you could face issues with older browsers, but then again you'll most likely come across the same issues by simply using material considering they use things like `transform` in their styling.

Comment: Knowledge is power!